# PKCanvasView does not change tools

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

The bug is quite simple, my canvas view does not respond to any of my picker. When i wanted to use the eraser, it keep using the pen.

When i debug it, the picker does change it value but it doesnt affect the canvas

debug example

```
TOOL PICKER  PKInkingTool(tool: <PKInkingTool: 0x282978f80 com.apple.ink.pen color=UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1 width=2.679941>)
```

I'm using SwiftUI, perhaps it have anything to do with swiftUi it self?

Here's my canvas code

```
struct CanvasView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var canvas:PKCanvasView
    let picker: PKToolPicker = .init()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView {
        canvas.drawingPolicy = .anyInput
        canvas.backgroundColor = .clear
        canvas.tool = PKInkingTool(.pencil, color: .darkText, width: 15)
        canvas.becomeFirstResponder()
    
        return canvas
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {
        picker.addObserver(canvas)
        picker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: uiView)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

My expectation is that my canvas coresponse it it picker as it should be

Comment: By doing `let picker: PKToolPicker = .init()` you're creating a *new* picker every time the view is updated. You'd need to store a reference to the picker. A `Coordinator` might be a good place to do that.

Comment: How about i bind it to a ViewModel ?

@Binding var  picker: PKToolPicker

Comment: or a single instance of picker i suppose

Comment: You really helped me there. do you not want to add it as an answer so that I could upvote you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
struct CanvasView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var canvas:PKCanvasView
    let picker: PKToolPicker = .init()
```

By doing this, you are creating a *new* instance of `PKToolPicker` every time `CanvasView` is created, which may be many times (every time this node of the `View` hierarchy is recreated).

Instead, you should store a *single* reference to `PKToolPicker`, such as inside a `Coordinator` or elsewhere passed into this `struct`